# Graphic understanding of derivative

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, graphing-functions, education

I'm about to teach some basics of Math and Phyisics to someone who studied Law and now want to start a Medicine Major. I'm a Phyisics student and I already got some good approaches for every topic, mainly graphic ones so everything wouldn't be so abstract at the beginning, but I'm struggling with the definition of a derivative because I don't find a correct connection between the graphic examples of a limit (they refer as the limit on one point and graphic examples are about approaching to one point of a function) and the derivative as a limit (graphic examples are about the secant lines being the tangent line in the limit). How can I make a good graphic way to understand the limit of a function being another function (a set of points not only one)?

Comment: I think the most productive approach would be to first graphically understand the exact definition of a limit (using epsilon, delta notation): https://brilliant.org/wiki/epsilon-delta-definition-of-a-limit/

Answer (score 1):

I made a [Geogebra visualization](https://www.geogebra.org/m/uffvw27t). You can probably find out how it works by yourself, but essentially, drag around the big blue dot along the graph of the function to obtain the graph of its derivative.